# VideoView Plays Video in other Activity as well

Tags: android, video, android-activity, android-tabhost, android-videoview

I have three activities in a tab Activity.I have to use video view in two activities.When I play a video in one activity it automatically plays video in other activity.How can I solve this issue?

Activity One Code:

```
        final VideoView videoView1= (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoViewPreviewVideos);
        final MediaController controller;
        String uriPath = "android.resource://com.robin.musicplayer/"+R.raw.bigsure30;

        final   Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);

        controller   = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);

        controller.setMediaPlayer(videoView1);
        videoView1.setMediaController(controller);
        videoView1.setVideoURI(uri);
        controller.setAnchorView(videoView1);
```

Code Acitvity 2 :

```
    String uriPath = "android.resource://com.robin.musicplayer/"+R.raw.treadmil;
    final   Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);

    controller   = new MediaController(this);
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this.videoView1);
    this.videoView1.setVideoURI(uri);

    controller.setAnchorView(videoView1);
    controller.setPadding(10, 500,10, 100);
    videoView1.seekTo(1);


    videoView1.start();
```